# Creating objects within loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, global-variables

What is difference in creating a string object within the while loop, assign different values in each iteration and create string object outside the loop and assign value in each iteration?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to try this yourself and step through it in the debugger?  You are expected to do your own research first.

Comment: this code creates an infinite loop. have you even tried it? typically you're supposed to try things out before asking questions.

Comment: Difference? The second one won't compile

Comment: this code is not been compile. what is x? if you use iterator instead of x, search about string constant pool.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat The first one won't compile either.

Comment: @Guy True . . .

Comment: the purpose of this question to get to know the difference in the variable assignment, whether different location is referenced every time or not.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong code, this is an analytic question

Comment: The compiler will make some optimizations if it sees a variable is assigned but not used. Someone already posted how you can look at the bytecode, so I encourage you to do the same - and change your code to use the variable in a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After compilation, as you can see there is no difference. You can view Java bytecode with `javap -c`.

```
C:\Users\y7017\Desktop>javac Test.java

C:\Users\y7017\Desktop>javac Test1.java

C:\Users\y7017\Desktop>javap -c Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
    public Test();
        Code:
            0: aload_0
            1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
            4: return

    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
        Code:
            0: iconst_0
            1: istore_1
            2: iload_1
            3: bipush        10
            5: if_icmpge     17
            8: ldc           #2                  // String Tester
            10: astore_2
            11: iinc          1, 1
            14: goto          2
            17: return
}

C:\Users\y7017\Desktop>javap -c Test1
Compiled from "Test1.java"
public class Test1 {
    public Test1();
        Code:
            0: aload_0
            1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
            4: return

    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
        Code:
            0: iconst_0
            1: istore_1
            2: iload_1
            3: bipush        10
            5: if_icmpge     17
            8: ldc           #2                  // String Tester
            10: astore_2
            11: iinc          1, 1
            14: goto          2
            17: return
}
```

**Edit: Added example code blocks removed from question.**

#### Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int iterator = 0;
        String name; 
        while( iterator < 10 ) {
            name = "Tester";
            iterator++;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test1.java

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int iterator = 0;
        while( iterator < 10 ) {
            String name = "Tester";
            iterator++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two code is the scope of the name variable.
name can be used in the body of the while loop only in the first code, while it can be used in the whole main body in the second code.